# groovyc ant task fails with fork="true"

Tags: ant, groovy

When I run groovyc without the fork option, it works fine. But with fork="true" it fails with an error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.ant.FileSystemCompilerFacade
```

What is wrong here?

Ant task:

```xml
<taskdef name="groovyc" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc" classpathref="test.path" />
<groovyc fork="true" srcdir="../myproject/src-test" destdir="${build.test.dir}">
   <javac debug="true" source="1.7" target="1.7" >
      <compilerarg value="-XX:-UseSplitVerifier"/>
   </javac>
</groovyc>
```

EDIT:
test.path contains a groovy jar:
`(...):/home/pkalinow/(..)/groovy-all-1.8.6.jar:(...)`

Comment: what does test.path evaluate to?  Does it really have groovy framework classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classpathref="test.path" must be specified in both <taskdef> and <groovyc> invocations when groovyc is forked.

I cannot find any confirmation in the documentation, but it seems, that only non-forking groovyc is inheriting classpath from taskdef.